# how can i fix this joi issue

Tags: reactjs, joi

I have a field and multi of conditionals, one of them greater than 0

```
barrageRadius: {
    key: "barrageRadius",
    label: "רדיוס מטח (m)",
    condition: Joi.number()
      .optional()
      .max(40)
      .greater(0)
      .messages({
        ...errorMessage.required,
        ...errorMessage.type.numeric,
        ...errorMessage.type.max.number(40000),
        "number.greater": "Value must be greater than 0",
      }),
    transferData: (val) => val / 1000,
    type: INPUT_TYPES.custom,
    validation: {
      max: 40000,
    },
  },

{
    "type": "number",
    "$_root": {
        "_types": {},
        "version": "17.6.0",
        "cache": {}
    },
    "$_temp": {
        "ruleset": null,
        "whens": {}
    },
    "_ids": {
        "_byId": {},
        "_byKey": {},
        "_schemaChain": false
    },
    "_preferences": {
        "messages": {
            "any.required": {
                "source": "שדה חסר",
                "rendered": "שדה חסר",
                "_template": null
            },
            "number.base": {
                "source": "השדה מוגדר כמספר",
                "rendered": "השדה מוגדר כמספר",
                "_template": null
            },
            "number.max": {
                "source": "40000 הערך התקין המקסימלי הוא ",
                "rendered": "40000 הערך התקין המקסימלי הוא ",
                "_template": null
            },
            "number.greater": {
                "source": "Value must be greater than 0",
                "rendered": "Value must be greater than 0",
                "_template": null
            }
        }
    },
    "_valids": null,
    "_invalids": null,
    "_rules": [
        {
            "name": "max",
            "method": "compare",
            "args": {
                "limit": 40
            },
            "operator": "<=",
            "_resolve": []
        },
        {
            "name": "greater",
            "method": "compare",
            "args": {
                "limit": 0
            },
            "operator": ">",
            "_resolve": []
        }
    ],
    "_singleRules": {},
    "_refs": {
        "refs": []
    },
    "_flags": {
        "presence": "optional"
    },
    "_cache": null,
    "$_terms": {
        "alterations": null,
        "examples": null,
        "externals": null,
        "metas": [],
        "notes": [],
        "shared": null,
        "tags": [],
        "whens": null
    },
    "$_super": {}
}
```

For some reason it doesn't any error when type an `0`